# Substituting part of string using .format() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I was working through a book on some advanced concepts of python and came across the following code block:

```py
SECRET = 'this-is-a-secret'


class Error:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

err = Error()
print(err.__init__.__globals__["SECRET"])
user_input = '{error.__init__.__globals__[SECRET]}'
# Results in accessing the globals dictionary of the object and then the value of secret
print(user_input.format(error=err))
```

According to the code, we can access the SECRET variable through the use of `.format()` which makes them a bit vulnerable. How are we able to access only the `error` part inside the {} block and substitute it with our `err` object.

What I see is that the `error` part is substituted with the object that we just created above.
Don't we require a complete substitution of what resides inside the {} block of the string? How does this process with `.format()` work.

Comment: I do not see the point of your exercise. Anyone can look up the value of a global variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the string format syntax (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), the `error.__init__.__globals__[SECRET]` part of the user input is `field_name` and `error` corresponds to `arg_name` and the rest of it is either `attribute_name` or `element_index`.

So the stuff inside `{}` in your user input is valid syntax for `str.format`.
When you give an argument to .format, it replaces the `arg_name` part only, and you don't need a complete match of what is inside the curly brackets.